# Kafka consumer does not resume processing where it last left off (Azure EventHub)

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, azure-eventhub

I'm struggling to configure processing of event messages. My goal: create a job that consumes events. Events are added to the queue continuously and my job is executed every 5 minutes. I want my job to process all events exactly where it left of on previous execution.

My setup:

- Azure EventHub - it's where events are stored. It has 24h retention
- Job uses `Confluent.Kafka` .NET client to communicate with EventHub

I've already configured consumer that can successfully read messages, but after in-depth testing I've spotted a problem. Here are steps to reproduce:

1. Generate a few messages and send them to EventHub (I see on a chart on Azure Portal that some messages were correctly delivered)
2. Then, run a job. Job starts `Consume` method but no events are read (it just timeouts)
3. After executing job: add more messages to EventHub
4. Events start to appear, but only those newly added. Events added at point 1. are missing

**In short: I'm losing events that are added to queue when job is not running.**

My `ConsumerConfig`:

```cs
var consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = $"{config.BootstrapServer}:{config.Port}",
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
    GroupId = config.GroupId,
    EnableAutoCommit = true,
    EnableAutoOffsetStore = false,
    MaxPollIntervalMs = config.MaxPollIntervalMs,
    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Latest,
    SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.OAuthBearer
};
```

My Consumer:

```cs
public async Task RetrieveEventsInBatchesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using var consumer = _kafkaClientFactory.CreateConsumer();

    consumer.Subscribe(_eventHubConfig.Topic);

    var batchContainer = new List<ProductPriceChanged>();

    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        var policyResult = _retryPolicy.ExecuteAndCapture((ct) =>
        {
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
            return consumer.Consume(_jobConfig.ConsumeWaitTimeout);
        }, cancellationToken);

        if (policyResult.Outcome == OutcomeType.Failure || policyResult.Result == null)
        {
            await ProcessBatch(consumer, batchContainer);

            break;
        }

        var consumeResult = policyResult.Result;

        if (consumeResult?.Message?.Value != null)
        {
            batchContainer.Add(consumeResult.Message.Value);

            _topicPartitionsOffsets[consumeResult.TopicPartition] = consumeResult.TopicPartitionOffset;
        }

        if (batchContainer.Count >= _jobConfig.MessagesBatchSize)
        {
            await ProcessBatch(consumer, batchContainer);
        }

    }

    consumer.Close();
}

private async Task ProcessBatch(IConsumer<Ignore, ProductPriceChanged> consumer, List<ProductPriceChanged> batchContainer)
{
    [...]

    StoreOffsets(consumer);
}

public void StoreOffsets(IConsumer<Ignore, ProductPriceChanged> _consumer)
{
    if (!_topicPartitionsOffsets.Any()) return;
    foreach (var offset in _topicPartitionsOffsets.Values)
    {
        _consumer.StoreOffset(offset);
    }
}
```

(I needed to remove some parts of my code so it might not be clear, but `_consumer.StoreOffset` is being ran properly. I've put a breakpoint to see if it is executed - and it is. So its not a problem with me not calling a Kafka method to store offsets)

So it seems like EventHub for some reason does not store offsets and when it starts to `Consume`, it automatically gets latest message (as configured in `AutoOffsetReset` in config). But if I understand correctly, `AutoOffsetReset` is just a fallback bahaviour, when no offsets are present. It should begin from last read message, isn't it?

Comment: Since you are manually calling StoreOffsets, you'll want to set EnableAutoCommit=false and ensure you commits are done manually